# resolveActivity() returns unexpected result for android.intent.category.APP_GALLERY

Tags: android

I want to change the default gallery apps of my system.
This is my IntentFilter:

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY);
    intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
```

And I have a similer Intent:

```
    Intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    ...
```

I use `myPackageManager.addPreferredActivity(...)` after `myPackageManager.clearPreferredActivity(...)` (or `myPackageManager.replacePreferredActivity(...)`) to replace the preference by my target app, but when I use

```
    ResolveInfo resolveInfo = myPackageManager.resolveActivity(intent, 0);
```

It still returns the default system Photos.

I can correctly get all the gallery apps (only two) in my system through codes below:

```
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = myPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

Both my app and the system gallery are in the list.
And I checked that they both have the priority 0, which means that they are equal.

I checked the `package-restrictions.xml` in my android mobile, and I found

```
    <item name="com.my.gallery/.MyGalleryActivity" match="100000" always="true" set="2">           
        <set name="com.my.gallery/.MyGalleryActivity" />                                           
        <set name="com.system.gallery/.SystemGalleryActivity" />                                     
        <filter>                                                                                       
            <action name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                                               
            <cat name="android.intent.category.APP_GALLERY" />                                         
            <cat name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />                                             
            <cat name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />                                           
        </filter>                                                                                      
    </item>
```

I believe that I have replaced the preference of gallery correctly, but why I still get the system gallery as default image viewer?

By the way, my android SDK version is 23.

Comment: "but why I still get the system gallery as default image viewer?" -- presumably, the user has not decided to make your app the default image viewer. Quoting the documentation for `addPreferredActivity()`: "This method was deprecated in API level 8. This is a protected API that should not have been available to third party applications. It is the platform's responsibility for assigning preferred activities and this cannot be directly modified."

Comment: @CommonsWare Well, in fact I am a platform developer and this API works well when I modify other default applications such as camera or video player.